# Sorting numbers numerically

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var a = [[11,"b"], [2,"b"], [11,"a"], [1,"a"], [1,"a"]];
a.sort();
alert(JSON.stringify(a));
```

gives:

```
[[1,"a"],[1,"a"],[11,"a"],[11,"b"],[2,"b"]]
```

how do I sort numerically?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the first element of the inner arrays will be **always** a number, which basing on you want to sort your array, you can just compare the first `[0]` from the inner arrays.

**Note**: `a[0] - b[0]` will sort elements in an ascending order.

```js
const a = [[11,"b"], [2,"b"], [11,"a"], [1,"a"], [1,"a"]];

const r = a.slice().sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(r));
```

Comment: [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) sorts in situ. the return of the same array looks like to get a new sorted array, which does not work like this.

Answer (score -1):

You can use underscoreJs _.sortby function

```js
var a = [[11,"b"], [2,"b"], [11,"a"], [1,"a"], [1,"a"]];
var b = _.sortBy(a,function(val){
    return val[0];
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(b));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```